# Use htaccess to change file names?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have done it before but have forgotten how i did it, but I remember I used htaccess before to make it where instead of saying http://website.com/Profile.php?name=myusername

It would say 
http://www.website.com/Profile/myusername

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ /Profile.php?name=$1
```